# how to use same block of code multiple times in perl

Tags: perl

Suppose, i have 100 if blocks with different if conditions but almost same code inside of if.

Example

```
if($a==3)
    {
    $xxx=6;
    #followed by 100 lines of code common to all if conditions
    exit #ie exit if condition is met
    }
if($b==9)
    {
    $yyy=9;
    #followed by 100 lines of code common to all if conditions
    exit #ie exit if condition is met
    }
#followed by 100 more if blocks
```

is it possible that i write common code somewhere and then use it by some one liner inside of my if blocks. This would save 10000 lines of same code.

I dont want to use subroutines since common code contains many variables which are assigned differently, for example, common code contains $a,$b,$xxx,$yyy and many other complications. All i need is to reduce my program length somehow.

Example

```
commoncode{
100 lines of code
}

if($a==3)
    {
    $xxx=6;
    commoncode;
    }
```

Comment: I think the real problem is, why do you have 100 `if` statements? If you can fix *that*, your other problem goes away.

Comment: Use subs, parameters, hashes, and evals if need be. All standard perl tech.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an x-y-problem, but I am going to answer the question anyway. This is old-fashioned stuff, and I would never use this kind of thing in production code. Or in run-once-and-forget throw away code either. But here goes...

You say you have a bunch of variables that are common to all the code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $foo, $bar, $qux );

# ... stuff happens

if ($foo == 1) {
  $bar = 'asdf';
  do 'commoncode.pl';
}
if ($foo == 2) {
  $bar = 'jkloe';
  do 'commoncode.pl';
}
```

I am using [the `do` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html), which loads a file of code and executes it right there in the same scope. This is pretty useful sometimes, but most of the time a horrible idea.

Now our *commoncode.pl* could look like this.

```
use feature 'say';
say $bar;
```

That's it. It will be executed in every block at run time when the Perl interpreter passes there. The file will be reread every time, which makes it slow. But it will get the job done.

---

But still, it's a bad idea and you should really think about a better solution to do this. Here are some suggestions:

- write a function and pass a lot of variables; that might seem tedious, but it will increase maintainability
- split the common parts that do share the same variables and write several small functions, then tie them together individually
- change the architecture so that you only have the common code after all your decisions, outside of those conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use closures to do this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define variables
my ( $xxx, $yyy ) = ( 0, 0 );

my $closure = sub {
    # common code that works on $xxx, $yyy
    print "xxx: $xxx\n";
    print "yyy: $yyy\n";
};

$xxx = 1;
$yyy = 1;
$closure->();

$xxx = 2;
$yyy = 2;
$closure->();
```

Output:

```
# perl test.pl
xxx: 1
yyy: 1
xxx: 2
yyy: 2
```

As others have mentioned, if this is not just a one-off script, you probably want to invest time to refactor the code to be more maintainable.

Comment: That's not a closure, and I don't see why this is better than using a regular named sub.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but that's a closure - its a very simple example of one, sure - but it fits the definition [http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-a-closure%3f]

I never said this is a "better" solution than regular named subs..  can this behavior be achieved with a regular sub? Sure. But since we don't know what the "common code" does here, I just gave an example of how you can abstract that sort of logic into an anonymous sub that can be repeatedly called.

Comment: A closure references lexical variables that are no longer in scope, but were in scope when the closure was defined. Every time the closure is called, these variables revert to the original values they had when the closure was defined. What you've shown can be done with a regular named sub; using a subroutine reference just makes the code less readable.

Comment: Ok, i will try this. Yes, my code is just to participate in a bot writing contest, nothing serious, so i dont want to spend time on improving it by using functions.

Comment: @user3388005 if it's a bot writing contest, how is the bot judged? Fastest development, fastest bot doing its job, or code quality?

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you asked that question! DRY programming (Don't Repeat Yourself) is a good principle to live by, whenever possible. In Perl, what you are looking to do is accomplished by subroutines.

```
if($a == 3)
{
  $xxx = 6;
  &mySubroutineForCommonCode;
}


sub mySubroutineForCommonCode
{
#100 lines of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's almost certainly a more elegant way to address your actual problem, but this is the most straightforward way to address what you've asked:

```
if($a==3){
    $xxx=6;
}elsif($b==9){
    $yyy=9;
} 100 more elsifs
...
}else{
    # handle case if no conditionals match
}

    #followed by 100 lines of code common to all if conditions
    exit; # (note you'll need a little more logic if you don't want to exit if no conditionals match)
```

Since you're only going to run your block of code once for the first conditional matched, literally all you need to do is 1) chain all the conditionals together and 2) move the common code outside of the conditional.